# Sorting linked list, swapping nodes

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to sort a linked list, but somehow during the swapping of nodes it goes into a loop.

I'm not allowed to just swap the values, HAVE to swap the pointers. Can someone please have a look and tell where I might be going wrong:

```
for (IntNode *index = head; index != 0; index = index->next)
    {
        for (IntNode *selection = head; selection != 0; selection = selection->next)
            {           
                 if (index->data > selection->data && order == 1) 
                  {
                      IntNode *prev1 = new IntNode;
                      IntNode *after1= new IntNode;
                      IntNode *prev2= new IntNode;
                      IntNode *after2= new IntNode;
                      prev1->next = NULL;
                      prev2->next = NULL;
                      after1->next = NULL;
                      after2->next = NULL;

                       for (IntNode *index1 = head; index1 != 0; index1 = index1->next)
                      { 
                          if(index1->next == index)
                          {
                              prev1 = index1;
                              after1->next = index1->next->next;
                          }

                          if(index1->next == selection)
                          {
                               prev2 = index1;
                              after2->next = index1->next->next;
                          }
                      } 

                      // now swap
            IntNode *tempPrev= new IntNode;
            IntNode *tempAfter= new IntNode;
            tempPrev->next = NULL;
            tempAfter->next = NULL;

            tempPrev->next = prev1->next;
            tempAfter->next = after1->next;


            prev1->next = selection;
            selection->next = after1;

            prev2->next = tempPrev->next;   
            index->next = tempAfter->next;
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. At the moment it is completely unreadable.

Comment: Why are you allocating new nodes? That just seems wrong.

Comment: Unless it's a function that adds an element, linked list code should never mention `new`. You don't need `new` whenever you create a pointer, you can just give it a value, like `IntNode *prev1 = 0;`. Debug by drawing the structure at each step with pencil on paper.

Comment: In linked list you habe always the special case of the first element. In that case you have to change the heade pointer additionally to any next pointer. Your code lacks this case.

Comment: @harper: is that the only case missing?

Comment: Still no luck, can anyone help

Comment: @rSU sorry I don't delve too deeply into code when I can see at a glance that it's plainly doing the wrong thing. If you rethink it and clean it up it might be worth a second look.